# PHP execution time - prevent Apache from stopping script

Tags: php, apache, shutdown

I am trying to get a PHP script under local Linux Apache running without getting stopped by Apache. I am using `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4`, `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`, `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit`.
What I did so far:

In my PHP script:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
...
foreach(...) {
    ...
    // inside loop
    usleep(1000);
    ...
}
```

In all `php.ini`:

```
max_execution_time=3600;
```

Nothing of the above helped. The script stops after ~30sec. Im out of ideas. Is it possible that my script gets shut down because it runs out of memory? Best way to check that?

EDIT:

Through adding "ini_set('display_errors', 1);" I got the error `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`. So it is about memory, thanks for the hint how to check that.

SOLUTION:

The underlying problem turned out to be the usage of 'foreach' loops. After switching all 'foreach' loops to 'for' loops the memory usage got more stable.

Comment: Do you launch your script from browser or from CLI?

Comment: Can you give us the error message that's shown? If you don't get one, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of the page

Comment: @TwiStar: browser - wasnt sure how well it would work from CLI since it's a whole framework (CodeIgniter) running.

Comment: @rjdown: E_ALL was already set but I added both of your statements in another place and now I get: "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted"

Comment: @rjdown: if you post your comment as reply, I shall accept it and close the issue! Thanks!

Comment: alright. hopefully this has helped you... but obviously we'll need to see more of your code if you need further help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what's causing the script to stop, add the following to the top of the page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
Only in http, if using https you must change your php.ini
Remember to reload your web server.